# Need help aligning my td element in the center

Tags: html, css

For some reason my td element (id='future_order') it not aligning in the center. I have done a lot of research online, but i didn't find anything that can help.

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

**css code**

```
#order_info_container{
    width: 600px;
    height:100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 40px;

}



#order_time, #future_order{
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;

    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 30px;


}
```

**Html Code**

```
<table id="order_info_container">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>
<img id="o_summary_logo" src="o_summary_logo,png">
  </td>
<td id="customer_service">
<b>
Customer Service # (212)-283-5751
<br>
Thank you for Business!
</b>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="future_order">****FUTURE ORDER****</td> <!-- This is not aligning in the middle -->
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Just need to add <td id="future_order" colspan="2">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use colspan="2" at the td you want to center, otherwise it will be centered just in that cell, and it will not center in the whole row.

```
<td colspan="2" id="future_order">text</td>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g4qH9/

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<td id="future_order">****FUTURE ORDER****</td>
```

to:

```
<td id="future_order" colspan="2">****FUTURE ORDER****</td>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MMZfL/)**